# Deadlock in multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, mutex

**I have deadlock in this code. It sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.**
I have the below simple code with 3 threads, and mutex. I want for every thread to wait and then after all are waited, signal the first one to run, and the one signal the second one and the second, third.

```
void *thread1(void *a) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   fprintf(stdout, "Thread %d.\n", 1);
   pthread_cond_signal(&cond);//release wait
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *thread2(void *a) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   fprintf(stdout, "Thread %d.\n", 2);
   pthread_cond_signal(&cond);//release wait
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *thread3(void *a){
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   fprintf(stdout, "Thread %d.\n", 3);
   pthread_cond_signal(&cond);//release wait
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, (void *) timer, (void *) timer);

pthread_cond_signal(&cond);//release wait
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Comment: What is `timer`?

Comment: The real code was so long rather I preferred to copy and paste the code's parts instead of writing them down whole. The whole mechanism of real codes is an abstract like above. ***Timer*** is a method, so suppose thread1 or 2,etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it possible that `pthread_cond_wait` of main thread will be executed after all executions of `pthread_cond_signal`. If main thread must wait termination of all threads, you can use `pthread_join`, or even semaphores, but I think it's a bit overkill.

Another problem is that first released thread (let say `thread1`) can release main thread (and not `thread2` and/or `thread3`), so you see output of only one thread, and then your program terminates. Once again it happens just because main thread doesn't wait for `thread1`, `thread2` and `thread3`.

Comment: True in very rare situation it is possible and I agree using pthread_join is reasonable. However the problem is "sometimes no thread prints out" . Do you think this belongs to the main thread blocking as you related?

Comment: @Metao , Ah, sorry, I'm a bit confused, so you problem is not deadlock but absence of outputs? If so, I edited my answer.

Comment: I presume to replace wait in main thread with join. However this does make a trivial deadlock. There should be a signal to take out one tread from the wait state.